# How to convert wmv to webm in c#

Tags: c#, converters, webm, wmv

I need to convert wmv to webm in my project. Maybe before upload maybe after upload i have no idea. Do you know any library or example code to doing that. I think it is not enough to change extension wmv to webm ?

Comment: could you see that one about it? https://www.mediasoftpro.com/aspnet-wmv-encoder.html

Comment: I'm not looking for encoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Nreco.videoconverter to convert which one i want to convert. It is useful but not providing support and examples for free version.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this job. A C#-Wrapper can by found on [github by tomaszzmuda](https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg).

The simplest approach to get the job done, would be:

```
Xabe.FFmpeg.ConversionHelper.ToWebM(@"C:\Input.wmv", @"C:\output.webm");
```

Comment: When i try to install xabe.ffmpeg at nuget give me error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Xabe.FFmpeg 2.2.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0" What should i do

Comment: @Er.Er As you can see on the [nuget site of xabe.ffmpeg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xabe.FFMpeg/) under dependencies: It requires .NET Standard 2.0.
On the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is a listing which .NET-Framework version fullfills the requirement. You need at least .NET-Framework 4.6.1